# Docker pull shows "Unknown blob"

Tags: asp.net, windows, docker, docker-machine

I'm trying to pull **microsoft/aspnet** image. It tries to download something and shows the progress. But then it shows an error - **"Unknown blob"**.

[image]

How I can solve this?

P.S. I have docker client and server v1.12.2

Comment: May the image available in the library might have problem. Experiencing the same here. If possible, report to the maintainer.

Answer (score 7):

Your docker version is 1.12.2 which does not supports Windows Containers, which means you are running Linux Containers in the VM. And you are pulling a Windows container based image so either update your docker to the 1.13.0 beta version which supports Windows Containers and pull this image or find a linux based image of .Net.

To see how to switch to Windows Containers, see this [GIF](https://i1.wp.com/blog.docker.com/wp-content/uploads/docker-for-windows-switch.gif?zoom=1.25&w=1140&ssl=1/)

Answer (score 5):

You must download and install latest docker from [here](https://download.docker.com/win/stable/InstallDocker.msi)

and switch to windows container.
[image: and switch to windows container.]

[read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-10)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not Windows/Linux cross compatibility.   A Linux client can pull Windows images, though it cannot actually launch them.

The issue 'unknown blob' is most likely image corruption.   Refer to other answer that mentioned that your image name is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to download a windows image to a Linux host. 
I'm assuming you're running the docker host within a Linux VM.

If you have access to Windows Server 2016 use that.

Comment: How can I verify it? microsoft/aspnet image is based on debian:jessie https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnet/~/dockerfile/

Answer (score 1):

try
`docker pull microsoft/aspnetcore`

Microsoft changed the names of their Docker Hub Repos in the last months so it is not so easy to find the right ones.